# TensorFlow Hidden Markov Model with more complex structure

Tags: tensorflow, hidden-markov-models, tensorflow-probability

Using the great TensorFlow Hidden Markov Model [library](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/distributions/HiddenMarkovModel), it is straightforward to model the following Dynamic Bayesian Network:

[image]

where H<sub>i</sub> is the probability variable that represents the HMM and S<sub>i</sub> is the probability variable that represents observations.

What if I'd like to make H depend on yet another HMM (Hierarchical HMM) or simply other probability variable like this:

[image]

The `HiddenMarkovModel` definition in TensorFlow looks like the following:

```
tfp.distributions.HiddenMarkovModel(
    initial_distribution, transition_distribution, observation_distribution,
    num_steps, validate_args=False, allow_nan_stats=True,
    time_varying_transition_distribution=False,
    time_varying_observation_distribution=False, name='HiddenMarkovModel'
)
```

It only accepts initial, transition and observation distributions.

How could I model the above and pass additional probability variable distribution to the `HiddenMarkovModel`? Is that possible by somehow incorporating `C` into the `transition_distribution` parameter?
Maybe `C` should be treated as observation as well? (I'm not sure though, if that would be a full equivalent of the structure I'd like to model)

A simple example / explanation would be great to have.

**UPDATE**

I've tried building a simple joint distribution of two dependent variables and feed as transition_distribution into the HMM:

```
def mydist(y):
  samples_length = 1 if tf.rank(y) == 0 else y.shape[0]
  b = tf.ones([samples_length], dtype=tf.int32) - y
  a = tf.reshape(y, [samples_length,1])
  b = tf.reshape(b, [samples_length,1])
  c = tf.concat([a, b], axis=1)

  condprobs = tf.constant([ [0.1, 0.9], [0.5, 0.5] ])
  d = tf.matmul(tf.cast(c, tf.float32), condprobs)
  return tfd.Categorical(d, dtype=tf.int32)

jd = tfd.JointDistributionSequential([
            tfd.Categorical(probs=[0.9, 0.1]),
  lambda y: mydist(y)
], validate_args=True)


initial_distribution = tfd.Categorical(probs=[0.8, 0.2])

transition_distribution = tfd.Categorical(probs=[[0.7, 0.3],
                                                 [0.2, 0.8]])

observation_distribution = tfd.Normal(loc=[0., 15.], scale=[5., 10.])

model = tfd.HiddenMarkovModel(
    initial_distribution=initial_distribution,
    transition_distribution=jd,
    observation_distribution=observation_distribution,
    num_steps=7)

temps = [-2., 0., 2., 4., 6., 8., 10.]

model.posterior_mode(temps)
```

This gives an error:

> ValueError: If the two shapes can not be broadcasted.
> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ndims'

The HMM manual mentions:

> This model assumes that the transition matrices are fixed over time.

And that transition_distribution must be

> A Categorical-like instance. The rightmost batch dimension indexes the
> probability distribution of each hidden state conditioned on the
> previous hidden state.

which tfd.JointDistributionSequential is probably not.

Still looking for a ways of building hierarchical HMMs with TensorFlow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TFP `HiddenMarkovModel` implements message passing algorithms for chain-structured graphs, so it can't natively handle the graph in which the `C`s are additional latent variables. I can think of a few approaches:

1. Fold the `C`s into the hidden state `H`, blowing up the state size. (that is, if `H` took values in `1, ..., N` and `C` took values in `1, ..., M`, the new combined state would take values in `1, ..., NM`).
2. Model the chain *conditioned* on values for the `C`s that are set by some approximate inference algorithm. For example, if the Cs are continuous, you could fit them using gradient-based VI or MCMC:

```py
@tfd.JointDistributionCoroutineAutoBatched
def model():
  Cs = yield tfd.Sample(SomePrior, num_timesteps)
  Ss = yield tfd.HiddenMarkovModel(
    ..., 
    transition_distribution=SomeDistribution(Cs), 
    time_varying_transition_distribution=True)


# Fit Cs using gradient-based VI (could also use HMC). 
pinned = tfp.experimental.distributions.JointDistributionPinned(model, Ss=observations)
surrogate_posterior = tfp.experimental.vi.build_factored_surrogate_posterior(
  event_shape=pinned.event_shape,
  bijector=pinned.experimental_default_event_space_bijector())
losses = tfp.vi.fit_surrogate_posterior(
  target_log_prob_fn=pinned.unnormalized_log_prob,
  surrogate_posterior=surrogate_posterior,
  optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(0.1),
  num_steps=200)
```

3. Use a particle filter, which can handle arbitrary joint distributions and dependencies in the transition and observation models:

```py
[ 
  trajectories,
  incremental_log_marginal_likelihoods
] = tfp.experimental.mcmc.infer_trajectories(
    observations=observations,
    initial_state_prior=tfd.JointDistributionSequential(
      [PriorOnC(),
       lambda c: mydist(c, previous_state=None)]),
    transition_fn=lambda step, state: tfd.JointDistributionSequential(
      [PriorOnC(),
       lambda c: mydist(c, previous_state=state)]),
    observation_fn=lambda step, state: observation_distribution[state[1]],
    num_particles=4096)
```

This gives up exact inference over the discrete chain, but it's probably the most flexible approach for working with dynamic Bayesian networks in general.

Comment: Thank you, Dave! This is very helpful.
After thinking for a while, I realised that _Hierarchical_ HMM is different to the picture that I've drawn (variable C). It is sad, that there are no free tools available to build HHMM models (e.g. for speech recognition, I'm aware about Google API for that). But the Layered HMMs https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layered_hidden_Markov_model seems to be  very close to my picture and it should be straightforward to chain TensorFlow HMMs for that.